# Selecting the newest row in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, timestamp

I have a database table containing a column called `timestamp`, which stores the system time for each of the rows inserted.

How do I select the row with the latest timestamp, i.e. the row that was inserted last?

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` is a reserved word in SQL Server (a datatype, actually) - I would try to stay away from those and use other column names...

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [tableName] ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: @Martin: Good catch. Corrected.

Comment: The table should definitely have an index on the timestamp.

Comment: The timestamp is of datetime DataType. Will it work? I am yet to execute the command.

Comment: It should. My answer will order your data according to their `DateTime` (timestamp) field, with the most recent items at the top, and it will choose only the first (most recent) row.